# CSS - Salesforce Picklists extra padding/margin on standard layouts? > select option

Tags: picklist, css, selectoption, chrome, browser

This seems to happen only in Chrome - I have tried the following:

- Removed all extensions
- Removed Profile
- Reset all flags
- Reset Settings
- Reinstalled Chrome

I even navigated to google\chrome\user data\default\ and looked for the "User Stylesheet" folder but it was not there.

As you can see from the screenshot below it I can even manually modify the option element styling in the DOM and something still isn't quite right:

[image: My Issue]

Below is what the status field looks like for other Chrome Users on the same record:

[image: normal view]

And finally, similar to image #1 - this is the look of a picklist without me overriding any styles in the DOM (still appears different that the rest of the users [screenshot #2])

[image]

Comment: Did all users go through the steps you provided to reset/reinstall chrome or just you?

Comment: Just me - but it appears to be just my machine. All other users see the 2nd image. Not the styling on 1 and 3.

Comment: So it's possible that all other users are simply using an out dated version of Chrome?

Comment: No I don’t think so, something is definitely funky with my machine. Others have the same version as me.